# How to get 'filetype' of a buffer specified by a number?

Tags: vim

I'm writing plugin for VIM and i need to know a `filetype` of buffer specified by a number. But `filetype` is an `option` - how can i get specified buffer option programmatically? I can get buffer name via `bufname()` vimscript function - but i did not found any function that allows me to get an option. Maybe it's some trick with `bufdo`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prefix the option with a **&**. E.g.

```
:echo &tabstop
:let myts = &tabstop
:echo myts
:let &ts = myts
```

See `:help :let-&`.

Other functions that you might need on your quest are:

- `getbufvar()` / `setbufvar()`
- `getwinvar()` / `setwinvar()`
- `gettabvar()` / `settabvar()`
- `gettabwinvar()` / `settabwinvar()`

See `:help var-functions`.

For simple cases you could also do something like this:

```
function! SetTabstopFromBufname(name)
  execute 'silent edit' bufname(a:name)
  let myts = &tabstop
  silent edit #
  let &l:tabstop = myts
endfunction

call SetTabstopFromBufname('vimrc')
```

Answer (score 5):

The `getbufvar()` function cannot just retrieve variables, but also buffer-local options (prefixed with `&`):

```
:let bufFiletype = getbufvar(bufNr, '&filetype')
```

Comment: It does seems to work for me using Vim 8.2 on Windows for the netrw buffers.